# Minimising interferences caused by switching low current

Tags: voltage-regulator, rf, switch-mode-power-supply, wireless, boost

For 2.4ghz radio devices, what are some good practices for minimising interferences caused by the boost converter on board? Suppose the input voltage is around 3V and output 5V <300mA. Even though the switching frequency is probably less than 600kHz, I wonder if the harmonics or other elements can cause substantial interferences that affect transmission (short/inefficient antenna).

Comment: Short current loops, proper decoupling, input caps with low ESR (and likely these days output as well), forced continuous mode operation if absolute maximum efficiency is less important.

Comment: To interfere with 2.4 GHz, you'll need the 4000-th harmonic to be strong enough. This is not going to happen with 5V and 300 mA, unless you essentially connect your antenna to the PSU (and even then, it won't be the harmonics that will screw up the 2.4 GHz part).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to limit the EMI interaction with the RF section, you need to slow down signals and damp ringing as much as you can. You can slow down the drain-source voltage rise on the MOSFET at turn-off by adding a small capacitor between drain and GND. Considering \$F_{sw}\$ of 600 kHz, this cap. can only be of low value (tens of pF) if you do not want to hurt efficiency (unless the boost converter operates in quasi-resonance). But its action will reduce the drain-source voltage rise considering a turn-off slope given by \$\frac{dV_{DS}(t)}{dt}=\frac{I_{peak}}{C_{lump}}\$ in which \$I_{peak}\$ is the current at turn off and \$C_{lump}\$ is the total capacitance lumped at the drain. If the boost diode current rings, you can calm it down by adding a \$RC\$ damper whose resistance is calculated to reduce the total \$Q\$ to 1 (\$Q\$ involves a parasitic inductance \$L_{par}\$ and a resonant frequency \$\omega_0\$ - calculate the resistance \$R\$ of the damper so that \$R=Z_{Lpar}@\omega_0\$ and then adjust the series dc-block capacitor to keep power dissipation under control). You can also use ferrite beads to damp unwanted oscillations. If you operate in CCM, carefully select the diode as its reverse recovery signature will affect the radiated spectrum. Finally, as correctly pointed out by Asmyldof, minimize as much as you can by proper component placement and PCB layout the loop areas in which high currents circulate at turn-on (source, inductor and MOSFET and return GND) but also at turn off (source, inductor, diode, output cap. and return GND). Keep layout compact.

Comment: Thanks for that. If I use the [LM2623](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm2623.pdf), will I still need a cap between drain and GND?

Comment: It is tough to say just by browsing the data-sheet. Sometimes parasitic contributors lumped at the drain are enough to snub the signal at turn off. You will have to wait for the prototype to check the obtained spectrum and see if it hurts your RF section or not. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

It is doubtful that it would directly interfere at 2.4 GHz but there are subsystems such as local oscillators, IF chains, etc. that could be affected.

Follow the spec sheet for the switcher with regard to PCB layout, bypassing, and Q of components. The use of EMI shielding techniques for the switcher and a solid LC low pass filter on the output will go a long way in mitigating potential interference. Don't overlook proper bypassing on the input connections of the switcher either.